# Repeat MinifiedJS function X times?

Tags: javascript, minifiedjs

I am using the library at minifiedjs.com. Using that script, I have a div blinking twice:

```
vbox1.animate({$backgroundColor: 'grey'}, 100)
.then(function() { return vbox1.animate({$backgroundColor: 'transparent'}, 100) })
.then(function() { return vbox1.animate({$backgroundColor: 'grey'}, 100) })
```

As you can see, it simply sets the background to grey, back to transparent, and then back to grey again. The problem is, I want this div to blink `X` number of times.

I know I could do this by simply chaining more `.then()` animations; but that seems a bit repetitive. Anyone mind helping me out on cleaning this up?

```
vbox1.animate({$backgroundColor: 'grey'}, 100)
.then(function() { return vbox1.animate({$backgroundColor: 'transparent'}, 100) })
.then(function() { return vbox1.animate({$backgroundColor: 'grey'}, 100) })
.then(function() { return vbox1.animate({$backgroundColor: 'transparent'}, 100) })
.then(function() { return vbox1.animate({$backgroundColor: 'grey'}, 100) })
.then(function() { return vbox1.animate({$backgroundColor: 'transparent'}, 100) })
.then(function() { return vbox1.animate({$backgroundColor: 'grey'}, 100) })
.then(function() { return vbox1.animate({$backgroundColor: 'transparent'}, 100) })
.then(function() { return vbox1.animate({$backgroundColor: 'grey'}, 100) })
.then(function() { return vbox1.animate({$backgroundColor: 'transparent'}, 100) })
.then(function() { return vbox1.animate({$backgroundColor: 'grey'}, 100) })
.then(function() { return vbox1.animate({$backgroundColor: 'transparent'}, 100) })
.then(function() { return vbox1.animate({$backgroundColor: 'grey'}, 100) })
.then(function() { return vbox1.animate({$backgroundColor: 'transparent'}, 100) })
.then(function() { return vbox1.animate({$backgroundColor: 'grey'}, 100) })
.then(function() { return vbox1.animate({$backgroundColor: 'transparent'}, 100) })
.then(function() { return vbox1.animate({$backgroundColor: 'grey'}, 100) })
.then(function() { return vbox1.animate({$backgroundColor: 'transparent'}, 100) })
.then(function() { return vbox1.animate({$backgroundColor: 'grey'}, 100) })
.then(function() { return vbox1.animate({$backgroundColor: 'transparent'}, 100) })
.then(function() { return vbox1.animate({$backgroundColor: 'grey'}, 100) })
```

Comment: Use a loop to append as many `.then` functions as you need.

Comment: How would you do this? All loops I've done execute all the loops instantly and don't follow the animation timings.

Comment: It returns a promise (i'm assuming). That's how the chaining works. You just need to add more `.then` functions in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the promise-y way:

```
function next() { 
   return vbox1.animate({$backgroundColor: 'transparent'}, 100)
      .then(function() { return vbox1.animate({$backgroundColor: 'grey'}, 100) })
      .then(next.total-- ? next : Boolean);
}

next.total=100;
vbox1.animate({$backgroundColor: 'grey'}, 100).then(next);
```

i use *next.total* instead of *x*, but the main idea is to self-call from the tail until you're done instead of looping/queing ahead of time.

EDIT:

as a re-usable (allows custom target, delay, and # of reps):

```
function animateMyStuff(target, period, reps){
   reps=+reps||100; //default and coerce to real number
   period=+period||100; //default and coerce to real number

    function next() { 
       return target.animate({$backgroundColor: 'transparent'}, period)
          .then(function() { return target.animate({$backgroundColor: 'grey'}, period) })
          .then(reps-- ? next : Boolean);
    }

    return target.animate({$backgroundColor: 'grey'}, period).then(next);
}
```

to use like before: `animateMyStuff(vbox1, 100, 100);` , or with defaults, `animateMyStuff(vbox1);`

Comment: Wouldn't this repeat forever? Not `X` times?

Comment: Hmm... this is nice... can I request a small change though? Right now vbox1 target is hard coded into the `next` function. Can you change it so that I can pass a target into the function instead?

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop:

```
var animation = vbox1.animate({$backgroundColor: 'grey'}, 100)
     .then(function() { return vbox1.animate({$backgroundColor: 'transparent'}, 100) });
for (var i=0; i < numberOfBlinks - 1; i++) {
    animation = animation.then(function() { return vbox1.animate({$backgroundColor: 'grey'}, 100) })
                .then(function() { return vbox1.animate({$backgroundColor: 'transparent'}, 100) });
}
```

You just append as many `.then` as you need.

Comment: I cant get this working at all... its not chaining the animations.